# a problem from general topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a metric space with metric $d$,and fix a point $x_{0}\in X$.
Let $\mathscr{T}$ be a topology on $X$ such that the function $f=$$d\left(x_{0},-\right):X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is countinuous with respect to $\mathscr{T}$. Show that $\mathscr{T}$ is finer than the metric topology.

In order to prove the desired result ,it's sufficient for us to prove that for any base of $X$ with respect to metric topology,there is an open set in $\mathscr{T}$ belonging to this base in metric sense. In other word ,we can prove that the collection of all sets $\{$ $f^{-1}\left(\mathscr{O}\right)|\mathscr{O}$ is open set in $\mathbb{R}$ $\}$ can generate the topology induced by metric $d$. Then I don't know how to achieve the goal.

Comment: Sorry,I corrected the statement where I missed few words.

Comment: Do you fix the point $x_0$?

Comment: I think so,Because this is what the exercise states.

Comment: If you consider $\mathscr{T}$ the topology where all  the open sets are the balls centered in $x_0$ then it isn't finer than the metric topology

Comment: I think you are right.Maybe the exercise itself has some problems.If we don't fix the $x_{0}$ and let it be any point in $X$, the statement will be right. Anyway,thank you for your discussion.

Answer (score 2):

The result is false. Let $X=\Bbb R^2$ with the usual metric, and take $x_0$ to be the origin. Let

$$\mathscr{T}=\{f^{-1}[U]:U\text{ is open in }\Bbb R\}\;,$$

and check that $\mathscr{T}$ is a topology on $X$; clearly $f$ is continuous with respect to $\mathscr{T}$, and $\mathscr{T}$ is strictly coarser than the usual topology on $\Bbb R^2$.

Note that it’s not hard to visualize the members of $\mathscr{T}$: if $U$ is an open subset of $\Bbb R$, $f^{-1}[U]$ is the set of all points in the plane that have polar coordinates $\langle r,\theta\rangle$ with $r\in U$ and arbitrary $\theta$.

Comment: Thank you for your example. I think the statement is false.

Comment: @mike: You’re welcome. It is indeed false. I see that the simplest way to make it true has been mentioned in the comments under the question: require $\mathscr{T}$ to make *all* functions defined like $f$ continuous, irrespective of the base point $x_0$.